# Need pointers on how report generation can happen in CQ5

Tags: aem

We have created a set of forms in CQ5 and we have a requirement that the content of these forms should be stored at a specific node, our forms interact with third party services and get some data from there as well, this is also stored on the same nodes.

Now, we have to give authors the permission to go and download these reports based on ACLs. I also will have to provide them start and end date and upon selecting these dates the content placed in these nodes should be exportable in CSV format.

Can anybody guide me in how to achieve this functionality. I have gone through report generation but need better clarity on how this can be achieved like how will i be able to use QueryBuilder api/ how can i export and how do i provide the dates on the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was achieved as described.

I actually had to override the default report generation mechanism and i created my own custom report using report generation tutorial in cq documentation.
Once the report templates and components were written, i also override cq report page component and provided input dates in body.jsp using date component of granite.
once users selected dates, with the help of querybuilder api i used to search for nodes at path(specified by author, can be different for different form data) and i also created an artificial resource type at nodes where i was storing the data, this lead me to exact nodes where data was stored and this property was also passed to querybuilder. The json returned as response from querybuilder was then supplied to a JS which converted the data to csv format.